# Total vs. Totales

Tags: plurales

I was just discussing this with a co-worker of mine. He wanted to use the word "totales" and I didn't think that was correct, so I immediately went to RAE to check but RAE didn't mention anything about it. Doing various searches we came up with very few uses of "totales" so he decided not to go with it, but is it really wrong to use that? It's for the sum of the rows in a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total:

> El total de personas afectadas por la lluvia llega a 250.

Totales:

> Los totales de las encuestas se sumaron y dieron como resultado un 40% de personas que prefiere una tablet a un portátil.

Total: singular.
Totales: plural (more than a *total*).

Answer (score 1):

For a single column in a table, its sum is a single number: "total".

For multiple columns, a row of per-column sums involves multiple numbers: "totales".